# How to install rosbridge on NAO robot

Tags: ros, rosbridge, nao, robot, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am thinking about a possibility to install rosbridge on NAO robot. I've got an idea but im not sure if its correct idea.
I am downloading (rosbridge) source files and put it into a VM where i've got a virtual NAO system.

1. I've installed there a ROS system. But what i do next.
2. I move download files to a directory my_workspace/src (this is a folder that was created during a tutorial "compilation From Virtual Nao": http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/compileFromVirtualNao)
3. and then i just run a command: src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
4. after a compilation i have to find dependencies and send them on the robot, where i've already installed ros system.

Do you think it would be right approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193829/how-to-install-rosbridge-on-nao-robot/) by [Maksym Figat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20338/maksym-figat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You're right that's exactly the way to proceed. The tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/compileFromVirtualNao explains how to cross-compile and install ros on your nao. But it's exactly the same process to cross-compile any ros package for your nao.

If you've troubles compiling/running the packages, you can update your thread on the SIG https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0